# Microsoft Graph API: how to use the "clear" endpoint and keep columns number format on excel file?

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, onedrive

My application uses Microsoft Graph API for inserting data on Excel Files. Before inserting the new data, we need to clear the previous one. The problem is that everytime we call the clear endpoint, all the number formating like currency, date, etc., is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clear` endpoint

```
POST /me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/names/{name}/range/clear
```

has optional parameter `applyTo` in request body which determines the type of clear action. The possible values are: `All`, `Formats`, `Contents`.

If you set `Contents` it should clear only values in cells and preserves formatting etc.

```
{
  "applyTo": "Contents"
}
```

Resource:

[range clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/range-clear?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body)